# cant seem to align text to the right wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

the left one seems to work fine other than small touching but the right one isnt really working anyway whatever i try its working on local host but when i try it online it dont can somebody point out the problem what am i doing wrong and for more info my default page max width is set to 1100px

```
<div style="max-width: 800px;">

<div class="box" style="margin-left: 50px; display: inline-block; width: 300px; height: 500x; text-align: left;">

<ul style="list-style-type: none; margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 48px; float: left; position: absolute; display: inline-block;">
    <li style="font-size: 15px; padding-bottom: 3px; padding-top: 20px;"><a href="http://www.google.com">Traps</a></li>
    <li style="font-size: 15px; margin-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 2px;"><a href="http://www.google.com">Shoulder</a></li>
    <li style="font-size: 15px; padding-bottom: 3px; margin-bottom: 2px;"><a href="http://www.google.com">Chest</a></li>
    <li style="font-size: 15px; padding-bottom: 5px;"><a href="http://www.google.com">Biceps</a></li>
    <li style="font-size: 15px; padding-bottom: 1px;"><a href="http://www.google.com">Abs</a></li>
    <li style="font-size: 15px;"><a href="http://www.google.com">Forearms</a></li>

       <li style="font-size: 15px; margin-top: 10px;"><a href="http://www.google.com">Quadriceps</a></li>
</ul>
<img class="aligncenter" style="width: 300; height: 400; margin-left: 115px; margin-top: 7px;" src="http://www.beyondshredded.pk/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/excercise-1-2.jpg" />

</div>

<div class="box" style="float:right;display: inline-block;width: 300px; height: 400px;">
<img src="http://www.beyondshredded.pk/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/excercise-2-2.jpg" style = "width:300; height: 500;margin-top:50px;margin-left:10px ">

<ul style = "list-style-type:none; margin-top:50px; float:right; position:absolute; display:inline-block; margin-right:100px;">


<li style ="font-size:15px;padding-bottom:25px; padding-top:15px;"><a href= "http://www.google.com">Neck</a></li>

<li style ="font-size:15px;margin-top:5px;padding-bottom:13px;"><a href= "http://www.google.com">Lats &#40back&#41</a></li>

<li style ="font-size:15px; padding-bottom:7px; margin-bottom:2px;"><a href= "http://www.google.com">Triceps</a></li>

<li style ="font-size:15px; padding-bottom:19px"><a href= "http://www.google.com">Middle&#40back&#41</a></li>

<li style ="font-size:15px;padding-bottom:3px"><a href= "http://www.google.com">Lower&#40back&#41</a></li>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>

<li style ="font-size: 15px; margin-top:10px;padding-top:3px;"><a href= "http://www.google.com">Calves</a></li>


</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A empty p tag is preventing the use if inline-block here. It works if you either remove the p tag or apply display: inline-block to it.

Comment: i dont see any p tag bro which line?

Comment: Inspect your site with FF or Chrome. It gets rendered like following:
div

Comment: div > img p ul. Can't say where it comes from by looking at your code(Maybe Wordpress is doing something here?). But removing it will display the ul right from the img

Comment: oh yeah there is an empty tag in inspect element but how do i remove it

Comment: I'm not that used to Wordpress so dunno how the rendering process is working here, sorry. Maybe wrap the img into the p tag like the other one and adjust the css of the p tag somehow (give it a class and set it to display: inline-block)?

Comment: umm ok let me check

Answer (score 0):

Give us link to your site. Probably you need to add extra class to your code and some CSS in theme settings.

Without CSS in THEME OPTIONS:

```
<ul style = "text-align:right; list-style-type:none; margin-top:50px; float:right; position:absolute; display:inline-block; margin-right:100px;">
```

With CSS in THEME OPTIONS:

```
<ul class="go-to-right"; style = "list-style-type:none; margin-top:50px; float:right; position:absolute; display:inline-block; margin-right:100px;">
```

in options:

```
.go-to-right{text-align: right}
```

Comment: Beyondshredded.pk/excercises

Comment: This is the link of the page

Comment: Beyondshredded.pk/training/excercises

Comment: <ul class="go-to-right" style = "list-style-type:none; margin-top:50px; float:right; position:absolute; display:inline-block; margin-right:100px;">

and then in theme settings

Comment: Ok i ll try and then get back to u

Comment: or just <ul style = "text-align:right; list-style-type:none; margin-top:50px; float:right; position:absolute; display:inline-block; margin-right:100px;">

But sometimes Themes ignore CSS styles (rewrite them) so then first option should work.